# UITableView doesn't show any cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a ViewController with a `UITableView` (and one type of `UITableViewCell`) set up through Interface Builder. I hooked that up to some `IBOutlets`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.allowsSelection = false
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(CommentTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CommentTableViewCell.identifier)
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150
}
```

Then I implemented the following methods:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(self.comments.count)
    return self.comments.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print(self.comments[indexPath.row], indexPath.row)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CommentTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CommentTableViewCell
    cell.comment = self.comments[indexPath.row]
    print(cell)
    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    let comment = comments[indexPath.row]
    return comment.user.isMe ? .delete : .none
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard editingStyle == .delete, !isDeleting else {
        return
    }

    isDeleting = true

    let comment = self.comments[indexPath.row]
    comment.delete() { result in
        self.isDeleting = false

        switch result {
        case .success:
            self.comments.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        case .failure:
            self.displayError("Could not delete comment")
        }
    }
}
```

Now this seems simple and all (print statements for debugging purposes), however, the tableView won't actually display any cells. After `tableView.reloadData()` is called, the `numberOfRowsInSection` method returns 2. The `cellForRowAt` also prints 2 `CommentTableViewCell`'s.

These are however not displayed. After some testing, I found out that the `tableview` itself however, is displayed.

Now why is it possible that this happens? I don't think I missed anything. Does anyone have experience with this?

Thanks :-)

Comment: try adding heigthForRowAtIndexpath datasource method and return a fixed value for test

Comment: @ReinierMelian Doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: Do you see any constraint break logs in the console?

Comment: Try adding `tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)` to your `viewDidLoad`

Comment: If you use Debug View Hierarchy, do you see that the table actually contains two cells / rows? If so, are the cell's frame heights Zero? Or, if  the cell heights correct, but you're not seeing any content in the cells, check the frames of the content elements.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `CommentTableViewCell` has this `comment` label, make sure the vertical constraints for the label are set correctly. The problem seems to be about the incorrect cell height.

As suggested by Reinier Melian, try out fixed heights to see if that works.
If not, temporarily change the cell to a `UITableViewCell`, and set the title label instead and make it work. That way, we can isolate the problem better.